# Sharepoint Online/365 list threshold limit

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365-developer

Just a small question.

As we know that threshhold limit is 5000 for sharePoint custom list.
But if i create different views say 3.
So we will have 15000 items or 5000 items ?

Comment: Please read this: https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-overcome-sharepoint-5000-item-limit-threshold/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, List items limit is 30 Million. List view threshold is for view purpose only which mean in a certain views you can not get more than 5000 items as it is limit online.

But you can have upto 30 million items. for large list follow the guide line here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2759051/the-number-of-items-in-this-list-exceeds-the-list-view-threshold-error

Comment: Thanks for reply. So i will create 'Indexed columns' and then will create different views and will filter with my created 'Indexed Column' ? So my problem will get resolved correct ? Actually i have 3 different categories therefore i was thinking about different views.

Comment: yes you can create 3 different views...

Answer (score 2):

The listview threshold simply means that you can't have more than 5000 items in a view.  You can have up to 30 million items in a list, but any views on the list can only expose 5000 items.  In your example, the fact that you have 3 views that expose 5000 items each, doesn't limit you to 15000 items.  It just means that at most, you can only *view* 15000 distinct items in those 3 views.

In on-prem Sharepoint you can increase the listview threshold but you don't have that option in Sharepoint Online.  You have to use indices, views, and/or folders to manage very large lists.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-sharepoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: Thanks for reply. So i will create 'Indexed columns' and then will create different views and will filter with my created 'Indexed Column' ? So my problem will get resolved correct ? Actually i have 3 different categories therefore i was thinking about different views. So my each view will have 5000 limit.